# What's the best way to visually sort data about characters?

Tags: characters, tools, scrivener, graphics, data

I have a couple of characters that I want to group together on multiple pages. Each could be about different information.

[image]

Another example would be, with 1 page for each period of time.

- Year 1: Alive: [A B C] Dead: [D] Missing: [E]
- Year 2: Alive: [A B] Dead: [C D] Missing: [E]

I was thinking of making simple images for each of the characters and using Google Slides to have one slide per year (for the example above), and pasting character pictures in accordingly. You can't do stuff like that in Scrivener, it gets way too slow with images.

What are the best tools you could use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions.

- Scapple: it‘s very flexible with both notes and images; however, it won‘t end up in nice tabular structures
- Gimp: at least want to mention it
- Office tools, both Microsoft or OpenOffice: spreadsheet, presentation; consider using databases
- Tikz and Latex: tikz provides nodes, which can include graphics, can be positioned free, bound, on a lattice etc.; Latex provide the host document for tikz, e.g. with `\documentclass{standalone}`

To clarify:

- Images are available according to the question
- Key task is to arrange several drawings.

Programs, which allow free hand positioning of drawings and other elements are:

- Scapple
- Gimp
- PowerPoint and its counterpart
- Tikz, if you want to use it that way, via ad hoc coordinates

Programs, which provide a regular or tabular like structure are:

- Spreadsheets
- Presentation
- Tikz, also Latex (kindly consult literature on both)

A database is a different approach to collect and retrieve character information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

##### I make a portable Wiki for each fiction.

It doesn't need to be portable (i.e. you could create a Wikia page for every character) but I like to use TiddlyWiki (TW henceforth) to document that. TW is an all-in-one Wiki system that has embedded Javascript in a HTML file. Just drag and drop into a browser window, and start editting. You can create a Wiki entry for every character, location, weapon, skill, power, plot, etc...

Being a wiki, you can create as many links between the entries as you like, making it easy to navigate between your references.

The amount of plugins is staggering. When you are done, just archive the file somewhere (or publish it online).